# wget flashcontent offline

Tags: local, swfobject, wget, offline, mirror

Im downloading a complete site for offline use:

```
wget \
     --recursive \
     --no-clobber \
     --page-requisites \
     --html-extension \
     --convert-links \
     --level=10 \
     --restrict-file-names=windows \
     --domains mysite.com \
     --no-parent \
         www.mysite.com
```

Everything works fine. Except local SWF files. They arent download by wget.

My question: how do I download (using wget) flash or swf movies (swfobject) like:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  // <![CDATA[

  var so = new SWFObject("/wp-content/swf/animation.swf", "animation", "205", "205", "6", "#FFFFFF");
  so.write("flashcontent");

  // ]]>
 </script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure wget will follow embedded-object links such as those used by Flash objects.  Why don't you try `httrack` instead?  Also, note that just because you fetched the SWF objects doesn't mean they'll work at all.  Flash can be making its own Internet connections, which obviously won't function offline.

Comment: In the sample you provide, it is simply a matter of wget not parsing out the javascript that is embedding the swf. That being said, if you want to go really deep with crawling sites with flash content, you may find the following useful: http://rhizome.org/editorial/2013/feb/25/preserving-flash/